# Inter-dependent dropdown menus: 'Expression has changed after it was checked' (Angular2 + Polymer)

Tags: angular, polymer

I understand that Angular checks for changes twice per round, and that this error is triggered when these do not return equal results. I just don't see why this code should have this problem, or how I can fix it.

example code available at: https://github.com/dirtysanchez69/issue-angular2-polymer-2

I have 2 dropdowns where one has its options populated depending on the other's selected value. (this works with no errors):

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Fruit" #fruitDropdown >
  <paper-listbox 
  class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item *ngFor="let option of dropdownOptions.fruit">{{option}}</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>

<paper-dropdown-menu label="Types (depends on Fruit)" [disabled] = "!fruitDropdown.value">
  <paper-listbox
  class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item *ngFor="let option of 
          (( fruitDropdown.value ) 
           ? dropdownOptions.type[fruitDropdown.value] 
           : [] )">{{option}}</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

The data is right there in the constructor:

```
constructor() { 
  this.dropdownOptions = {
    fruit: ['apple', 'grape', 'banana'],
    type : {
      apple: ['granny smith', 'red delicious', 'macintosh'],
      grape: ['sirah', 'bordeaux'],
      banana: ['plaintain', 'baby', 'manzano']
    }
  };
  this.userData = {
    fruitSelection: 1,
    typeSelection: 1
  };
}
```

[image]
[image]

However, if I add a [selected] value to the item-listbox (default selected index), it gives the error: **EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: 'sirah,bordeaux'**

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Fruit" #fruitDropdown >
  <paper-listbox 
  [selected]="userData.fruitSelection"
  class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item *ngFor="let option of dropdownOptions.fruit">{{option}}</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Is there a better way to do this? What's the problem here?

Comment: Whee do you add a `[selected]` value?

Comment: On the paper-listbox (refer to last code snippet)

Answer (score 1):

As [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068290/updating-children-of-polymer-elements-using-angular-doesnt-cause-parents-to-relo/38081679#38081679), Polymer in shady mode does not play nice with Angular2. Enabling Polymer's shadow mode globally solved this issue.

The team behind [@vaadin/angular2-polymer](https://github.com/vaadin/angular2-polymer) (the integration library used here), is aware of and working on improving the shady dom adapter. Check out the [Issue](https://github.com/vaadin/angular2-polymer/issues/34).

If you are experiencing difficulties of this kind, add this script to your index.html

```
window.Polymer = {
  dom: 'shadow',
  lazyRegister: true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, with such an error, you need to force the change detection leveraging the `ChangeDetectorRef` and its `detectChanges` methods.

Here is a sample:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  someMethod() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

See this question:

- [How to dirty-check iterable component property in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377871/how-to-dirty-check-iterable-component-property-in-angular2/35378046#35378046)